# How to decode unknown encoded string in python, tried chardet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, decoding, chardet

I don't know encoding type of string and I want to decode that string.
I have tried chardet `python` module but didn't work.

I know output of string, is there anyway i can decode string using python...

Example

```
Input
'\x06@\t\xa6'

Output
104860070
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You will find probably find it quite difficult to decode the string without knowing the encoding method.

Comment: are you sure it is string and not `int` packed with `struct.pack()` or `pickle` ?

Comment: @furas i got above result from a struct.pack() and i store in a string variable.

Comment: then use `struck.unpack()` to get value again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is text created with `struct.pack()` so use `struct.unpack()`

```
import struct

result = struct.unpack('!i', '\x06@\t\xa6')[0]
print(result) 

# 104860070
```